# Cannot boot aarch64 alpine linux on mac os using QEMU 6.2.0

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, macos

I'm trying to run alpine linux using `qemu-system-aarch64` on a mac M1/apple silicon, however, instead of booting from the provided ISO, I always get QEMU monitor [1].

The following works without any problem, it boots from the ISO and eventually I get to login and have the shell available as I would expect (note that it's `x86_64`):

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -boot d -cdrom ~/Downloads/alpine-standard-3.15.0-x86_64.iso -m 2048
```

When I try to do (in my opinion) very similar with aarch64 version, I get the aforementioned QEMU monitor instead (apparently there is no default machine so I use `virt`):

```
qemu-system-aarch64 -boot d -cdrom ~/Downloads/alpine-standard-3.15.0-aarch64.iso -m 2048 -machine virt
```

Ultimately, my goal is not to emulate but use the new `hvf` which became available with QEMU 6.2.0, therefore I assume I'd run something like this, but again, I only get the QEMU monitor window:

```
qemu-system-aarch64 -boot d -cdrom ~/Downloads/alpine-standard-3.15.0-aarch64.iso -m 2048 -cpu host -machine virt,highmem=off -accel hvf
```

Do you have any suggestion as to what I'm doing wrong?

[1] The monitor is a separate window with some sort of interactive shell and says the following (I tried the help, but didn't find anything relevant):

```
compat_monitor0 console
QEMU 6.2.0 monitor - type `help` for more information
(qemu)
```

Comment: running into same issue, qemu-system-x86_64 on apple silicon works well, while qemu-system-aarch64 doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue on Linux, but was able to get it working by following instructions from here:

http://www.redfelineninja.org.uk/daniel/2018/02/running-an-iso-installer-image-for-arm64-aarch64-using-qemu-and-kvm/

tl/dr:

You must first create and specify `pflash` disk image and `virtio` variable store files.

```
qemu-img create -f qcow2 varstore.img 64M
qemu-img create -f qcow2 alpine.img +20G
```

And boot with a suitable QEMU EFI file.

```
wget http://snapshots.linaro.org/components/kernel/leg-virt-tianocore-edk2-upstream/latest/QEMU-AARCH64/RELEASE_GCC5/QEMU_EFI.img.gz
gunzip QEMU_EFI.img.gz
```

Run:

```
sudo /home/user/qemu-6.2.0/build/qemu-system-aarch64 \
-cpu cortex-a57 -M virt -m 2048 -nographic \
-drive if=pflash,format=raw,file=QEMU_EFI.img \
-drive if=pflash,file=varstore.img \
-drive if=virtio,file=alpine.img \
-drive if=virtio,format=raw,file=alpine-virt-3.15.0-aarch64.iso \
-net nic \
-net user \
-no-reboot
```

Comment: Two questions: 1) why the `-nographic`? I can boot into the installer with that but I only get the monitor with omitting it, and 2) Qemu (at least from homebrew) comes with a suitable EFI image: what is the point of downloading that one? Which, by the way, made my macOS kernel panic.

Answer (score 0):

**@guest**'s answer works for me. My answer is a supplement. (I was going to post it as a comment, but I found it has a little more words than I thought)

I was running into the same issue, either with `qemu-7.2.0` which is from `Homebrew` or `qemu-7.1.0` which is from `Macports`. And what I have is a Macbook Pro 16inch with chip "Apple M1" and macOS Monterey 12.3.

What I learned is -- it seems that the `qemu-system-aarch64` needs UEFI to boot up, the legacy BIOS doesn't work. (Google "*qemu aarch64 uefi*", the examples in all of the articles/blogs/documents in the first google page show that the `qemu-system-aarch64` are invoked with UEFI image)

Therefore, my final command line is like this,

```
qemu-system-aarch64 -m 512 -smp 1 \
    -boot d -cdrom alpine-virt-3.17.0-aarch64.iso \
    -nographic \
    -M virt,accel=hvf,highmem=off \
    -drive if=pflash,format=raw,file=edk2-aarch64-code.fd -cpu host
```

`edk2-aarch64-code.fd` is the UEFI image coming with the package `qemu`, which is in the folder `/opt/local/share/qemu/` for `Macports`, or `/opt/homebrew/share/qemu/` for `Homebrew`.

And I found that I have to use `-cpu <...>` with it. I tried the following cpu, all works. And doesn't work without it.

```
host
max
cortex-a57
```

I also found it might not be necessary to use a small image as the EFI variable store (as the `varstore.img` mentioned in **@guest**'s answer). I am not 100% sure of this, since I didn't do a full test.

(`-nographic` is just my preference)